# Capacitor's energy required for a predetermined drop in its voltage - with LDO and constant current elements as load

Tags: power, capacitor, energy, energy-harvesting

I am trying to understand how much energy a circuit (composed by some passives here called analog, and an MCU) will require. The system is powered through a capacitor, and the "passives" are actually some low power op amps attached directly to the capacitor, like the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6qgBq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The MCU is powered through an LDO, and has a determined active time while otherwise is in sleep (now for simplicity I consider sleep equal to 0mA), but the active part is always on.

I need to understand how much energy the system requires to have a predermined drop in the capacitor voltage. From such results, I will define the next design steps or various tunings.

The approach was to compare the total energy required, given the capacitance in consideration, with $$ E = \frac{1}{2} C (V_{0ms}^2 - V_{10ms}^2) $$

The MCU activates with a given duty cycle, and I need to calculate the energy balance only in this period of time, with a given MCU duty cycle. Example, the MCU wakes for 1ms every 10ms, so duty is 1ms and period is 10ms. Duty cycle is 10%. I only want to know the power balance over 10ms, because afterwards the capacitor will gets fully recharged before the next cycle.

But here the problem:

- I can calculate how much drop in the capacitor voltage I have with a given energy, but because the energy can be rewritten in $$ E = P t = V I t $$, I can use this form to check, in the duty time activity, how much energy is drawn form the MCU, LDO and active components and check it against the capacitor's energy calculated in the initial formula (related to a given drop).
- Despite this assumption, because the energy is th eintegration of the power over time, I am not sure if makes sense to calculate the energy of the active part in this way: $$ E = (V_{0ms} - V_{10ms}) I_{active} t_{10ms} + (V_{0ms} - V_{10ms}) I_{MCU} t_{1ms} + (V_{0ms} - V_{10ms}) I_{MCU sleep} t_{9ms}$$  What would be the right approach?

Comment: Right from your first formula you have inbuilt an error. Energy does not equal the change in capacitor voltage squared. You cannot treat energy and voltage this way.

Comment: hi, thanks for pointing out. I copied from my previous question without editing what I meant. maybe is still wrong, but at least if what I thought to use

Comment: If you use my answer in your previous question, the formula is correct and all you need to worry about is current draw, voltage drop and time to calculate a value of capacitance.

Comment: yes, thanks. the thing is that I am not sure how to translate the formula when the voltage is constant (the MCU is powered through an LDO). I guess I need to use the power of the LDO - voltage drop of the capacitor used as input of the LDO and constant current of the MCU when is active, so I have V, I and time to find the energy. I think the assumption makes more sense now..

Comment: @Andyaka I edited the question as now is much less confused. I hope you can check it. otherwise I am willing also to make a new question with this content again. I think my problem is a very naive one though, maybe is not needed to make a new question?

Comment: Are you saying that the capacitor (C) gets charged cyclically and that you want to make sure that between charge events, it holds up enough voltage to keep the whole circuit operational? If so, then we need to understand timings such as how long the capacitor is recharged for, the time interval when it doesn't receive charge, the peak voltage that it charges to and how much the capacitor voltage can fall without stopping correct circuit functioning.

Comment: I just want to understand how to compare energy quantities, and the analysis can be done in 1 cycle, with C full. I don't need to know if the system will hold over the cycles (as you rightly suggest) but I only need to find a way to compare the energy of the capacitor, with the energy required by the attached components over a certain period of time. As known variables I have the current consumption of all, capacitance, voltage, allowed drop, time of utilization. We can assume that capacitor is immediately charged after, or we can wait as much as we want to charge it, so we don't care for that

Comment: So that I can see, when C is fully charged, if I can just change the duty cycle of the MCU in case the energy in C is not enough. what happens after 10ms is not part of the question. I hope this still makes sense. and if not, why?

Comment: So no, I don't need to find if C gets charged enough - I assume it now-, but I needto know only if the activity of the circuitry is enough to keep itself operating over the activity time (10ms), compare the energy of the load, with the energy available and check the feasibility form that

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding the question and I'm probably wasting your time with my misguidance.

Comment: Do you think is accepted to rewrite a smaller question from scratch? I would like to investigate my problem, but also not annoy anyone that are giving their time for free. What would be best? Maybe is optimal also for you or anyone willing to answer?

Comment: I think you can salvage your question by rephrasing it in comments and attracting my attention to see if I then understand it. Then, when I do, you should give Stefan the option of answering it. If he's OK with a full deletion of this question (after it has evolved into something he and I understand) then you should ask a new leaner and meaner question.

Comment: Hi, I put an answer to describe better what I had in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, rephrasing what I found so far, also thanks to discussing in the comments, I think it might help to write a new answer to myself, as I need to put also some graphics in it.

My problem is that I have a theoretical capacitance, and naturally it loses potential as long as the energy is taken from it. This capacitance is used to power some devices, which in the end are not important, it just matters that such devices are taking a known amount of constant current for a known period of time. The capacitor has a known initial voltage, and it is known the minimum allowable voltage we need.

The energy the capacitor can provide, is $$ E_{c} = \frac{1}{2} C (V_{init}^2 - V_{final}^2) $$.

The energy the devices are using can be found through the usage time and their current, but the voltage is dropping. So is NOT possible to assume $$ E_{used} = (V_{init} - V_{final}) I_{active} t $$, because I am interested in finding the total energy used to make such drop in C, not just it's delta:

[image]

So in order to find the energy the devices are using (is the first area in the graph), I must simply do some geometry:

$$ E = P_{min} t_{max} + \frac{(P_{max} - P_{min}) t_{max}}{2} $$

And finally I can compare this to the original energy the capacitor can provide to see if the circuit will stay within specifications.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't understand what you are trying to find out or why you want to do this. I'm not being awkward (I can be of course!) - I'm just not following what you are trying to evaluate or why.

Comment: There is a device, which harvests energy from a capacitor and I need to adjust the duty cycle of the MCU to use all the energy down to the minimum allowed voltage. I assume the MCU to have constant current (it is powered through a LDO so it sees constant voltage). The meaning of the device is not relevant, as the question is on the mathematical side of it, and not if the product makes sense or not. The only unknown is how to find the energy used by the MCU and to check if will be greater than the energy the capacitor can provide. Because V is not constant, I had some doubts in doing so.

Comment: But this takes us back to your earlier question surely. If you know the voltage drop rate and you know how much current the load takes you can calculate the capacitance AND, if you want to know how much energy that capacitor has dispensed between Vupper and Vlower use A - B where A = \$\dfrac{CV_{upper}^2}{2}\$ and B = \$\dfrac{CV_{lower}^2}{2}\$

Comment: "If you know the voltage drop rate and you know how much current the load takes you can calculate the capacitance" how? from the E = V I t? My approach in the answer doesn't makes sense? Isn't possible to see how much energy the capacitor can provide , and compare it to another energy quantity, which is what the load requires? If is higher, then I need a bigger capacitance. So maybe your approach helps in finding first the capacitance needed, then comparing it with my actual capacitance, and this will give the same answer I am looking for. but then, how?

Comment: \$C = I\cdot \dfrac{dt}{dv}\$. Example: I = 10 mA and dv = 1 volt and dt = 1 second then C = 10,000 uF.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Of course, this makes sense, and then I can convert back to energy numbers by doing $$ E = 0.5 C (V_a^2 - V_b^2) $$. Just for me instead, my geometrical approach doesn't makes sense?

Comment: Correct - the main part of the answer was in your previous question all the time i.e. \$I = C\dfrac{dv}{dt}\$. Just rearranged for the above.

Comment: and yes! numerically, I have the same energy by using the geometrical approach. which is just the same in the end (I call geometrical just because I draw the concept), but at least I convinced myself I was thinking straight.

Answer (score 1):

I'm now sure if I understand your question right. I think you want to know (based on the capacitor voltage drop) how much energy is absorbed by the "always on" (static) circuit and how much by the MCU (dynamic) circuit? 
If you only know the voltage difference of the capacitor (dV) from t=0ms to t=10ms, then this is not possible to calculate, because you have two degrees of freedom in the equations. 
You would need to measure the capacitor voltage drops of the dynamic or the static circuits each alone.

Also, like Andy aka wrote, your formula is not right: The right one would be 
$$dE=\frac{1}{2}CV_{0ms}^2-\frac{1}{2}CV_{10ms}^2$$

Comment: hi, I corrected the initial formula. my mistake!

Comment: can't I consider two theoretical cases one with the static and the other with the dynamic consumption? In both cases knowing an initial voltage and the capacitance. Maybe averaging the MCU peak current over the whole period? In the end it would be the same.... My problem is that becuase there is an LDO, I can't use the assumption of the voltage drop, as it is kept constant. So I guess I should approach in a different way

Comment: I do not get what you‘re after. Can you explain more about your problem with the LDO? Which voltage drop is kept constant?

Comment: I just want to calculate the total energy taken from the capacitor to make it drop from an initial voltage to a final one, to maximize quantitatively the duty cycle of the MCU considering the static current consumed by the other components, and not going through trial and error (I would not learn much by doing so, either)

Comment: I think my last comment on Andy Aka's make the point but I am not sure is the right way. If I realized how to calculate the energy from a cap by calculating a certain drop over time, I am not sure how to calculate in the same way when the load is supplied from an LDO. But is a stupid question, as I think it is enough to consider the MCU current in the same way as the static one. Because the current of the LDO is the same as the output, I can just consider the drop on the input of the LDO with the MCU current for the MCU duty time duration. There should not be more than one degree of freedom:

Comment: 1. voltage drop is defined by my own requirement,
2. capacitor is known,
3. current is known
4 time is known
5.... something is missing to make another additional degree of freedom?

Comment: It could be really helpful if you 1. draw a schematic of your circuit, 2. tell us what you want to optimize and 3. show us the degrees of freedom you have.

Comment: Ok. if so far is clearer what I am after, the problem is related to a meaningfulness: if E = VIt, how can I find the energy for the delta voltage? Is it enough to consider the energy difference given two different voltages? Like dE = dV I t ?

Comment: Ok, I will notify when I edited the question

Comment: dE is not dV/t. dE is calculated based on the formula in my answer.

Comment: Hi check the edit... the text was formatted and inserted a / because I used the asteriscs.. I meant dE = dV I t

Comment: Hi, I think now is much more clearer.  I hope you are still willing to check it. sorry for that

Comment: What I wrote on Andy's comment might be useful too, to understand the question

Comment: Ok, i think i got your question now. Let me explain: You can only apply the E=UIt formula when your circuit draws a constant current from the capacitor. But this might not be the case in your circuit.

Comment: Exactly, but I assume constant current. I found a plausible mathematical approach that includes the variation of V, I am preparing an answer to myself. If you have time, you can check if my solution makes sense. I will notify when I complete the answer.

Comment: Hi, I put an answer to describe better what I had in mind